# Do dispatch in Redux middleware cannot trigger state change in connect mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

I am writing a Redux middleware, and I am willing to do dispatch before & after reducer functions called, sample middleware code as follow:

```
const myMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: true }})

    next(action)

    dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})
  }
```

I also use react-redux to connect Redux store with React like below:

```
@connect((state, ownProps) => {
  ...

  return {
    xxx
  }
})
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    ....
    return (
      ....
    )
  }
}
```

But why mapStateToProps always return `xxx=false`, while xxx could be
true and false observed by Redux Devtool extension?

Comment: Can you share `ownProps` object?

Answer (score 2):

Because dispatching is synchronous, and you're resetting the flag back to `false` before React has a chance to re-render.

If you add some logging to your `mapState`, what I would *expect* to see is that `mapState` is actually running for both dispatched actions.  However, React won't render until after the entire dispatching sequence is done, so the first update gets batched with the second, and you never see a render with the `true` value.